# How to append value to an array only if not exists and remove it if not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this `initialArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to add this `[1,2,3]`

**1 /** If `[1,2,3]` exists in the `initialArray`, I want to remove it from `initialArray`.

So the results will be `[4,5,6]`

**2 /** Then I want to add `[1,2,3]` again, and now `[1,2,3]` is not exist anymore in that `initialArray`.

So in that case, results will be `[4,5,6,1,2,3]`

**3 /** Now I want to add `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. So in that case, results will be `[]`

I tried to use `.filter()` to remove existing values, and it works. But I can't "concat" if values doesn't exist. I have not been able to do **both**.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const initialArray = []; // your initial array
const add = []; // stuff you want to add

const { filtered, toAdd }  = initialArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const index = acc.toAdd.findIndex(v => v === curr);
    index === -1 ? acc.filtered.push(curr) : acc.toAdd.splice(index, 1); 
    return acc;
}, { filtered: [], toAdd: [...add] });

const final = [...filtered, ...toAdd];
```

And if your initialArray had duplicate values you could just do,

```
const initialArray = [...new Set(initialArrayWithDuplicates)];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use indexOf method, so it might look something like this (basic example to gave you an idea):

```
var index = array.indexOf(item);
if (index !== -1) array.splice(index, 1);
```

think about this also, code below will acctually check if the value you tried to insert to array exist allready inside, so it will remove it:

```
for(var i = arrayWithNumbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(arrayWithNumbers[i] === number) {
       arrayWithNumbers.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steffi If my question helped you accept it as answer please.

Comment: I upvoted yours, but I already accepts another answer which works too, but thank you <3

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the array to add and seach for the index and ither push the value or splice the array.

This solution mutates the original array.

```js
function add(target, source) {
    source.forEach(v => {
        var p = target.indexOf(v);
        if (p === -1) {
            target.push(v);
        } else {
            target.splice(p, 1);
        }
    });
    return target;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

add(array, [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(array); // [4, 5, 6]
add(array, [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(array); // [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
add(array, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
console.log(array); // []
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this, mutating the original array could be this:

```js
const initialArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const toggleElements = (array, change) =>
    array.toString().includes(change)
        ? array.splice(array.indexOf(change[0]), change.length)
        : array.push(...change);

toggleElements(initialArray, [1,2,3]);

console.log(initialArray);

toggleElements(initialArray, [1,2,3]);

console.log(initialArray);
```

Comment: Yeah! That works too! Thank you very much!